# Handling two surfaceViews

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have two surface Views
1> MediaRecorder display surfaceview.
2> MediaPlayer SurfaceView displaying the Media recorded by MediaRecorder.

I want to display both the views simultaneously on the screen z ordered.

The mediaPlayer will be palying in full screen and the MediaRecorderPreview shd appear in the top right corner with some smaller size.

I am able to do this using two surfaces but the issue is that the MediaRecorder Preview always goes to the background z order and gets hidden by the mediaplayer full screen display.

Is their any way to define the Z order of Surface View.

Or is their any other suzzestion i can do to make this work. Can i start both MediaRecorder and MediaPlayer in a single surface?

Pls suggest. Thanks!!

Comment: And how you are trying to achieve that? Always share code, so that we can try to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to display both the views simultaneously on the screen z ordered.

AFAIK, that is not supported by Android. Android cannot composite multiple `SurfaceViews`. It can handle a regular `View` (e.g., `Button`) on top of a `SurfaceView`, but not two `SurfaceViews` Z ordered.

I recommend redesigning your application to have a single `SurfaceView` at a time.

Comment: Hi Commonsware, Can i display both MediaRecorder Preview and MediaPlayer view in a single SurfaceView. Pls suggest. Thnx.

Comment: @Deva: That is not possible, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

As of Android 2 (API level 5) having 2 surfaceviews is supported. You can set the zOrder of the 2 surface views using [setZOrderMediaOverlay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29) although apparently it breaks the [intended semantics of SurfaceView](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/yaLEszDg_Eo/db196Oyj81kJ).