# Android: Simultaneous video playback and recording

Tags: android, video, media, media-player, recorder

I'm developing a video chat like application for Android. Can I record and play video on the screen at the same time? Can I compose the videos over one another (FaceTime style) or do the y have to be side by side? Can I use the MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder classes or do I have to use lower level APIs?

Answer (score 2):

Avner,

To answer to your question bit wise

1> Can I record and play video on the screen at the same time?
Ans : yes you can.

2> Can I compose the videos over one another (FaceTime style) or do the y have to be side by side?

Ans: You can not have PIP(Picture in picture) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521674/handling-two-surfaceviews)

you can go for a side by side option.

3> Can I use the MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder classes or do I have to use lower level APIs?
ans: yes you can use these.

Comment: how can I do this ?any sample or any example ?