# Android: record video while playing another simultaneously

Tags: android, video

I'm creating an android app that requiers recording video and playing a video at the same time. I've been able to do it in IOS but i don't know if it's even possible to do it in android. So my question is; is this possible?

Comment: got an answer to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853842/android-simultaneous-video-playback-and-recording?rq=1)! :)

Comment: "requiers recording video and playing a video at the same time" 1. Do you mean preview of recorded video? 2. Recording video from where? screen or camera? 3. playing video from where internet/local stream?

Comment: Record a video on which camera u wont on the phone, and simultaneously stream a video on to the screen is what i want. Did that answer your question?.