# Smooth transition between different videos using VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I’m trying to achieve the following:

1. Play a long video from the web using a VideoView
2. In Parallel buffer a short video from the Web
3. After X Seconds, pause the long video and Play the short one
4. When done playing the short video, I resume the long video

I need the transition between movies will be as smooth as possible
I’ve tried to achieve this by several methods using ICS:

1. Use two VideoViews on top of each other and toggle between them, but I had Z-ordering issues
2. I’ve took the code of VideoView and modify it to have another MediaPlay inside it to buffer and play the short movie

Option number 2 works on ICS, but when trying on Android 2.3 it failed to work, I’ve read that having two MediaPlay objects running in the same time is not guaranteed to work.

My question is how can this be achieved using Android 2.1 or higher?

Answer (score 0):

The option 1 is never a possiblity as you can not have two SurfaceViews/VideoView z ordered on the same screen.
PFB the link which states the same thing:

[Handling two surfaceViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521674/handling-two-surfaceviews)

Comment: Maybe is is possible by moving one to a negative postion (-1,-1) and settings its size to be 1?

Comment: I think as of API level 5 you can have 2 surface views and order their z index with [setZOrderMediaOverlay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean))